# System won't start after installation of Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've installed the Ubuntu 12.04. But the problem is when I try to install the Nvidia driver, I chose recommended version and when installation finishes, I reboot my system but all I see is a black screen and system doesn't starts and stays on a black screen also the mouse can't move. I've tried 3 times but problem continues.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very similar to ones I have been experiencing.
After installing NVIDIA driver (either 'current' or 'current updates'- makes no difference)  rebooting will fail to load graphics. NOTE: I also had the same problem during (clean) install, so if you did not, below may not be appropriate for you.
To circumvent this, at the grub menu highlight your normal choice, but press 'SHIFT' + 'e' (on occasion I have had to press 'e' twice). This should allow you to edit the configuration that Ubuntu will load. Use the arrow keys to move down to the line containing the words "quiet splash". Delete "quiet splash" and replace with "nomodeset" and press 'CTRL' and 'X' to save your change and return you to the Grub menu. You then press 'Enter' normally and you should see Ubuntu loading. Good Luck! If this does allow you to boot Ubuntu, then you will either need to repeat the procedure each time you boot or (preferably) make the Grub change permanent. There is already an answer somewhere for this (try [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation)).

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to get with your real problem but it seems you installed the recommended driver and stuck somewhere after reboot, is it? Do this if u can: Run the Recovery mode when system boots up and run the broken packages and restart again.Update your system and still the problem sustains,then come here and update your question with details of what you did.